# Use view as Crystal Report datasource in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I want to use Crystal Reports in my website and I want to display two different tables in my report.  As I underrstand, I should use a View, but I don't know how should I use it, or what code I should write in my code behind for Crystal Report viewer?

Can you tell me what should I do from here?

Comment: Are you confused on how to create the crystal report? Or how to add it to your webpage?

Comment: I am confused on how to add a crystalreport with "View" to my homepage(I have added view(instead of table) to a dataset and after that have exported it to mycrystalreport.rpt but,I don't know what should I do in my hompage executing this report!!!)

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET with .aspx pages?

Comment: yes,I am using asp.net

Comment: I added an answer that hopefully will help. Or do you need help converting the data in your view to the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `CrystalReportViewer` control to the page that you want to show the Crystal Report on:

```
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" 
                            runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

Then in your code:

```
    ReportDocument myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    myReportDocument.Load("TheNameOfYourCrystalReportFile.rpt");
    myReportDocument.SetDataSource(yourDataSet);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
```

Once you set the ReportSource, it should prompt you for parameters.

Look at here for references for [CrystalReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa665020%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [ReportDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691469%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For loading your xsd file into a dataset:

```
    DataSet yourDataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXmlSchema("DataSet1.xsd");
```

Comment: thank you so much,I have problem with MyReportDocument.setdatasource();you know I add new Item to my project named DataSet1.xsd(and I have it in my solution explorer) and drag the View1 to it's design surface; so how should I use this dataset in ....\\\.setDataSource() command?

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to load an xsd file into a `DataSet`

Comment: thank you,we have some progress!!it load the print page and columns but it doesn't show any data and any fileds!!shouldn't we use the connection string or some command ????

Comment: it solved,I used the select commnad from View1 and it reported the data,Thank you so much for your good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are working with SQLServer, in order to create a view, use the “Create View” statement using the following convention:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vStoreAccountNum
AS
SELECT AccountNumber
FROM Sales.Customer
WHERE CustomerType = 'S'
```

And If you are totally new to Crystal Reports I would advise you to play a bit with the sample database that is attached to Crystal Reports `Xtreme.mdb` before you will use Crystal in Visual Studio.

To use CR in your application follow this step by step tutorial:

> **Step 1**: Right click the solution Explorer and click on add new item
>
> **Step 2**: Add a Crystal Report from the Dialogue box.
>
> **Step 3**: Select the Radio Button(using the Report Wizard) from the
>   Crystal Reports Gallery and choose a Standard Expert and click OK
>   button.
>
> **Step 4**: Here we have to add Database..Select the Create New
>   connection from the available Datasources window and click OLEDB(ADO)
>
> **Step 5**: select A new connection and then select a provider from the
>   list (Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server)
>
> **Step 6**: Enter the server name and select the Database and click the
>   Integrated Security and press next and click finish button.
>
> **Step 7**: Now,come back to Standard Report Creation Wizard and select the
>   Table from the Database.
>
> **Step 8**: Select the required fields to
>   display in the Crystal Report from the table
>
> **Step 9**: Select the style from the availble styles window (Ex:Standard)
>   and Click Finish
>
> **Step 10**: Now we have to add one WebForm from Add New Item and press
>   Add.
>
> **Step 11**: Here,we have to import two references that is
>
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine   CrystalDecisions.Shared
>
> **Step12**: Now,add one Crystal Report Viewer from the Toolbox
>
> **Step13**: Now we have to import the following namespaces in the
>   defalut.aspx.cs
>
> using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
>   using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
>   using System.Data.SqlClient;
>
> **Step14**: Declare the variable ReportDocument report = new
>   ReportDocument();
>
> **Step15**: Next,write the following code in the page Load Event
>
> pt.Load(@"E:\practices\AppTestdetails\crystalreports\CrystalReport.rpt");
>   crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
>   crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

Good Luck!

Comment: Hey why you are angry?! then you have make an effort to do that we will not write the code for you! visit whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I'm not angry at all and  I didn't want you to write for me the code!!! I want to use view instead of tables in my dataset,I have maked this view but I don't know how shuould I use it in my crystalreport,just this

Comment: See this tutorial using datasets for WinForms it's the same thing for ASP.Net http://thariya.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-create-basic-crystal-report.html

Answer (score 2):

You no need to create a view just to display data from more than one table. In crystal report add the tables and then provide the join between the tables. These joins gives single result set to the crystal report.

From the result, you can pick the data.

Comment: ok! first note: how can I provide join between my tables; and another note:suppose that I have joined them ,what coding should I use instead of ???>:: command.CommandText=????, adapter.fill(dataset,????),SetDataSource(dataset.Tables[????]);